# rootContext && dispatcher-servlet are not being initialized

Tags: spring-mvc

I am newly learning Spring MVC and facing a problem. I have configured my project correctly and all things were going well .For some reasons, I have done maven clean than maven install than update project.After that, if I run the project ->->-> rootContext && dispatcher-servlet are not being initialized. In the console just the following->

Dec 05, 2016 11:20:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1093 ms
Dec 05, 2016 11:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 801 ms

and in the browser->

HTTP Status 404 - /st/add

type Status report

message /st/add

description The requested resource is not available.

If I change the workspace and in a new project just paste the previous configuration, it works again.

How can i solve the problem without copying and pasting again and again?????

My project tree is-

-- src

```
 -- main
   -- webapp
     -- WEB-INF
       -- spring
            --rootContext.xml
            --dispatcher-servlet.xml
       -- web.xml
```

As IDE, I am using Spring Suit Tool (STS) and as server Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition.

Comment: Which is your webapp folder and where in the project tree is it? And, are you using eclipse or other ide?

Comment: has been added in the question....